How to fix issue login url "https://km.wso2.com:9443/console" buffering continously on WSO2 Idenity Server
I deployed WSO2 API-Manager in Distributed. And I use WSO2 Identity Server 6.1.0 as a Key Manager. I already fixed the issue /console and /myaccount "Registered callback does not match " using this steps.
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.2.0/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-invalid-callback-error/
Then I tried to login "https://km.wso2.com:9443/console" and "https://km.wso2.com:9443/myaccount" wso2 identity server portal buffering continously. After taking too much time, this error message appears in the logs and still buffering.
{org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve} - Error while normalizing the request URI to process the authentication: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 8: /console wso2 identity burring continously
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2974)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3145)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3227)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3186)
        at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623)

I used the default encryption, and this is my deployment.toml configuration
Use resource: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/
[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://cp.wso2.com:3306/shared_db?useSSL=false&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true"
username = "sharedadmin"
password = "sharedadmin"
driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

#Traffic Manager Endpoints Configuration
#Use Same Configuration

#Use default-encryption
[keystore.primary]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
password = "wso2carbon"

[truststore]
file_name="client-truststore.jks"
password="wso2carbon"
type="JKS"

#Event listener endpoint to publish controller events to the Control Plane
[event_listener.properties]
notification_endpoint = "https:/cp.wso2.com:9443/internal/data/v1/notify"
username = "${admin.username}"
password = "${admin.password}"
'header.X-WSO2-KEY-MANAGER' = "WSO2-IS"

#Disable group and role separation
[authorization_manager.properties]
GroupAndRoleSeparationEnabled = false

How to fix "https://km.wso2.com:9443/console" portal buffering continously. What changes should I do ?
Have any suggestions to fix this issue ?

can i know the configured callback url for console?

"regexp=(https://km.wso2.com:9443/console|https://km.wso2.com:9443/t/(.*)/console)"
